# adding radio button values in separate groups using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a form with radio buttons that I'm using javascript to loop through and return the sum of all the radio buttons to an input element at the bottom of the page. The script I'm using is this and it works fine.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function checkTotal() {
var radios = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=radio]'),
    sumField = document.querySelector('input[type=text]');
    var sum = 0;

    for (var i = 0, len = radios.length - 1; i <= len; i++) {
        if (radios[i].checked) {
            sum += parseInt(radios[i].value);
        }
    }
    sumField.value = sum;
}
</script>
```

Here's my form http://cognitive-connections.com/Prefrontal_Cortex_Questionnaire.htm

However I need to build another form where there are several questions in different groups and I need to sum the totals for each group separately and post them to their corresponding input elements on the page accordingly. Here's my new form http://cognitive-connections.com/Prefrontal_Cortex_Questionnaire100913.htm

I'm not an advanced javascript user but do have a pretty good understanding of programming itself (I think, lol) My head tells me that I should be able to simply declare a unique var for each different group and a unique element to post it's results to and use the same loop (with correct vars for each group) for each group. But when I add [name="elements name"] as the identifier for the document.querySelectAll it grabs the elements with that name only and if I name the elements themselves the same name the radio buttons loose their inherent property of only letting one radio button per question be selected at a time? I've also tried creating a class id for each group and tried to use it as the identifier in the document.querySelectAll and it doesn't seem to work at all then. Any help is greatly appreciated..

Comment: jquery is good for you?

Comment: Please post the relevant code (HTML, CSS as well as JavaScript) *here*, post demonstrations to a site where we can see, and edit, the code, such as [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/), [Dabblet](http://dabblet.com/) among many, many others. Digging through your website is not as much fun as you might imagine, and creating updates/amendments far, *far* more difficult than it should be. Help us to help you, and you'll tend to get better, and faster, answers.

Comment: I figured it out, my thoughts were correct I just needed to make sure all my variables were correct.  thanks anyway..

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding of question, below is my answer. And here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/8sbpX/10/.

```
function enableQ(cls) {
  var ele = document.querySelectorAll('.' + cls)[0],
    ev = (document.addEventListener ? "#addEventListener" : "on#attachEvent").split('#');
  ele[ev[1]](ev[0] + "change", function () {
    var radios = ele.querySelectorAll('[type="radio"][value="1"]:checked').length;
    ele.querySelector('[type="text"]').value = radios;
  });

}

enableQ("rad-grp");
```